# How to put client id and production auth key on paypal express checkout sandbox

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, braintree, express-checkout

This My code on the below code client section I have to add production key and client token.

```
<script>

    // Render the PayPal button

    paypal.Button.render({

        // Pass in the Braintree SDK

        braintree: braintree,

        // Pass in your Braintree authorization key

        client: {
            sandbox: paypal.request.get('/demo/checkout/api/braintree/client-token/'),
            production: '<insert production auth key>'
        },

        // Set your environment

        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

        // Wait for the PayPal button to be clicked

        payment: function(data, actions) {

            // Make a call to create the payment

            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: { total: '10', currency: 'USD' }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        },

        // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.tokenize().then(function(data) {
                console.log('Braintree nonce:', data.nonce);
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button-container');

</script>
```

how to get client id and secret auth from paypal express sandbox ,because 
I have to add them on the below code.

```
client: {
            sandbox: paypal.request.get('/demo/checkout/api/braintree/client-token/'),
            production: '<insert production auth key>'
        },
```

I have entered our sandbox app auth key and id I am getting error.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am getting error"?

Comment: Paypal express checkout not open when I enter app credential
but if I dont enter anything it works but amout not show

Answer (score 0):

If your production credentials are not correct you the PayPal Light box will not open.

Your code should look similar to this: (Sandbox and Production Client id listed below is from the demo page as an example):

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client -

```
  client: {
            sandbox:    'AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R',
            production: 'AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R'
        },
```

Here are the steps to getting your Sandbox and Live Client ID:

1. Go to PayPal Developer site https://developer.paypal.com
2. Click on Log into Dashboard (use your live PayPal credentials)
3. Click on My Apps & Credentials
4. Scroll down to Rest API apps
5. Click on the App that you Created (or create an app)
6. Copy Sandbox Client ID
7. Click on Live at the top right
8. Copy Live Client ID

Comment: I have tried this but when I add this I dont get Iframe of sandbox paypal